# Can Chaos Bolt leap back to a previously hit target after jumping?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

If you cast Chaos Bolt on target 1 and then it jumps to target 2 and can jump again, does it need go after target 3 or can it go back to target 1?

In other words: can Chaos Bolt strike at the same target more than once?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## No

> You hurl an undulating, warbling mass of chaotic energy at one creature in range. Make a ranged spell attack against **the target**.[...] If you roll the same number on both d8s, the chaotic energy leaps from the target to **a different creature** of your choice within 30 feet of it. Make a new attack roll against **the new target**, and make a new damage roll, which could cause the chaotic energy to leap again.

Each creature getting hit by the bolt is considered a new target.

However, the spell specifically says at the end:

> A creature can be targeted only once by each casting of this spell.

Which means that a creature  that has been previously hit (targeted) by the same casting of *chaos bolt* cannot be selected as a target again.